# TeX in DokuWiki: wrong rendering

Tags: tikz-pgf

I believe, this code is correct. I include it into an article, my DokuWiki installation (Miktex/Windows) renders it, but it is only 8x16 pixels:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1, 3);
    \draw[thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (A);
    \node[above right] at (A) {$A = (1, 3)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

At the same time when I get rid of the text node, it works:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1, 3);
    \draw[thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

How would you try to overcome this?

**Update.**

The engine produces this TeX:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{MyColour}{rgb}{0.50,0.00,0.00}
{\color{MyColour}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1, 3);
    \draw[thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (A);
    \node[above right] at (A) {$A = (1, 2)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\end{document}
```

And the first conversion .tex > .dvi looks good. But the second .dvi > .ps ruins it (dvips.exe -E tmp.dvi -o tmp.ps). Binary files: https://yadi.sk/d/hBXNFn5tSp0NYg

Comment: As is tradition on this site, we cannot work with sniplets like this, please provide full examples that others can copy and test as is. Also you should probably explain how you convert to images (as LaTeX does not output pixel images)

Comment: The DokuWiki LaTeX plugin uses imagemagick to crop the pictures, so it must be going wrong there. https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:latex

Comment: The configuration looks sane: https://github.com/marklundeberg/dokuwiki-plugin-latex/blob/master/conf/default.php I copied their preamble and added TikZ to it (http://dpaste.com/2JQNK3B expires in 7 days), then compiled with `latex` and `dvips` and threw it into `convert test.ps -density 120 -trim -transparent "#FFFFFF" test.png`.  The result looks good: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqaxW.png

Comment: @daleif, reasonable enough. I'll update the question.

Henri Menke, I tried that chain, and the produced result looks wrong after the dvips...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem is in the command line for dvips. It includes "try to create EPSF" key "-E". No idea, what it was for. Works better without it (for now).

And I'm not alone with this issue: https://github.com/marklundeberg/dokuwiki-plugin-latex/issues/10